# Is it possible to cool with ions?

Tags: thermodynamics, electric-fields, plasma-physics

I had an idea to use ions for cooling/refrigeration, but I assume it won't actually work but can't figure out why not.

The idea came from the idea that if you had a bucket full of ping-pong like particles in a of smaller and smaller size, they would eventually begin to bounce upwards do to thermal energy alone. If you had some apparatus above these balls that caught the ones that bounced high enough (like a pipe with a funnel on it) when they fell in, you would be removing thermal energy from below so the bucket would get cooler. This would be because the thermal/kinetic energy is converted to gravitational potential energy as it moves upwards.

I wondered if something like this would be possible, but the ping-pong balls would be monatomic gas (say neon) and the force would be electric force instead of gravity. The goal is to cool an "inside" area, while transferring heat "outside". You would have a pair of electrodes "outside" that would ionize the neon gas, stripping an electron on the positive side and then it would move to the negative side. The negative side would be electrically insulated (say with glass) though so when it got there, it would not recombine with an electron. The negative side would also be cooled with a fan with the "outside" air, so it would be approximately the same as the outside temperature. So when the ion interacts with it, it also becomes approximately the outside temperature. The ion is attracted the the negative electrode, but the thermal energy makes it "jump" above it a certain distance periodically. Above the negative electrode there would be an apparatus to "catch" these at the peak of their jumps, when there velocity/kinetic energy is very low. This apparatus, interacting with these "cold" ions would therefore become cooler and would be used to absorb heat from the "inside". The caught ions would find there way to another negative electrode to be recombined with an electron and returned to the start to start the process again.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is there no 'one way valve' for gas the doesn't require as much energy as air conditioning already would.

If some particles leave, then the air pressure outside is already greater than the air pressure inside and air will return through whatever valve the particles escaped through. If you try to funnel the particles downward so that that it's harder to come back up - remember that air pressure increases the further down you go, so the net gain of that effect is 0.

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear, this would be inside an evacuated container with just some amount of neon gas inside that is ionized (like a neon lamp).